# In powershell, how to return exit code of a subscript to the calling script

Tags: powershell, return, exit-code, subscript

**Powershell:**
While calling a subscript from a script, if the subscript is exiting with failure (i.e. exit code not 0), the main script is still exiting with exit code 0, showing as success.

Since subscript command is executed in script there is no error from main script side. **How to make main script read the exit code of the subscript to show exit code as failure?**

I had tried to return value before exiting from subscript and to call it in main script or using the $lastexitcode value, but those didn't worked.

Main Script:

- AppendFile.ps1

  ```
  function ExitWithCode
  {
      param
      (
          $exitcode
      )
      $host.SetShouldExit($exitcode)
      Write-Host "($exitcode)"
      exit
  }
  #..... Do something

  #Calling subscript from main script
  & C:\Testappendfile.ps1
  if ($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0){
      ExitWithCode -exitcode 321
  }
  else {
      ExitWithCode -exitcode 0
  }
  ```
- TestAppendFile.ps1

  ```
  function ExitWithCode
  {
      param
      (
          $exitcode
      )
      $host.SetShouldExit($exitcode)
      Write-Host "($exitcode)"
      exit
  }

  $FileExists = Test-Path C:\Files\check.txt
  If ($FileExists -eq $True){
      ExitWithCode -exitcode 0
  }
  else {
      ExitWithCode -exitcode 321
  }
  ```

If filepath is incorrect, then I am getting in output:
(321)
(0)

instead of
(321)
(321)

Comment: did you try `$error[-1]` to get the last error message generated in the session? Any other answer will require you to post your code.

Answer (score 1):

```
trap { $host.SetShouldExit(-1) }
```

Comment: This need to be used in child script if I'm not wrong. But i'm unable to get the result.            I am already using the $host.SetShouldExit ($exitcode) in both my scripts, so my result at end of execution of main script is coming as: Exit Code 1                                                            Exit Code 0